# jQuery .val Enigma between two input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm trying to get it so that if I move a red div-square around the screen using jQuery UI and jQuery, then an input field updates with the position of the div.  I got that working with a simple .val.  But, it's hard to explain why, but I need to make it so that when I move the square, it updates my input box, and when the input box value is changed, another input box reflects the new value of the old input box.  Do I make any sense, coz I'm confusing myself :).  I made a jsfiddle, so perhaps it'll make more sense there.

If you move the red square, then the input box directly above it updates, but the input box above that does not, even though it is programmed to reflect the value of the input box below itself.

P.S. Is this specific to only jQuery, or is this problem present in all of JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/xmCsq/27/

Comment: "... it is programmed to reflect the value ..." where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger the event manually if your setting the value in code, for example

http://jsfiddle.net/xmCsq/30/

Also why are you using the keyup event?

edit: never mind, I misread what you were trying to do.

Comment: no reason, that's what I thought I was supposed to do.  am I doing it wrong?

Comment: how come the value of the input box, the coordinate, is only updated when you hover your cursor over the div?

Comment: well i would have used the change event since your not actually typing/keying in anything in the input.

Comment: oh, well, I wanted to be able to type a number into the input box and have it update on the div

Comment: Your welcome (the "never mind" was because I didn't realize at first that you wanted to update in both directions (the red box the inputs, and the inputs the red box)).

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code a tad. The issue was that the name your chose for #other's val, `value`, was already taken by Javascript's language. Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmCsq/31/).

EDIT: Oh, misread your question. Updated the demo; the reason your second box wasn't updating is because you forgot to set it to update when you let go of the draggable box. :)